# Call subreport multiple times and pass value from array

Tags: sorting, loops, jasper-reports, subreport

I have a Main Report and three Subreports (they have different sizes).
I have an array which gives the order in which those three reports should run (003, 001, 002 for example - meaning report 3 will run first, then 1, then 2).

Is it possible to have one placeholder for a subreport that loops through the array (3 times in this case only) and then adjusts the size of the subreport it calls (also adjusting the path based on array value in the subreport expression of course)?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use DB connection in a sub-report, you can construct SQL query from the array, some thing like:

```
select '003' as rep_order
 union all
select '001' as rep_order
 union all
select '002' as rep_order
```

and pass it to a sub report to use it as a query. In query editor for sub report write something like:

```
$P!{ARRAY_QUERY}
```

Then in this sub-report add a sub-report element in a details band. For the above query it will run 3 times...

If you are going to generate query in a report you cant loop thru array so you'll have to hard-code number of array elements...